# grails hibernate query not working inside integration test

Tags: hibernate, grails, dns, integration-testing

I have the following domain class:

```
package gcbgb

class Score {
    Double victoryPoints

    static belongsTo = [ player:Player, gameTable:GameTable ]

    static constraints = {
        victoryPoints nullable:true
    }
}
```

which represents the number of `victoryPoints` a particular `Player` received while playing a game at a particular `GameTable`.

I also have a service:

```
package gcbgb

import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional class RoundService {

    int tableRank(Score score) {
        return Score.findAll("from Score as s where s.gameTable = ? and s.victoryPoints >= ?", [score.gameTable, score.victoryPoints]).size()
    }

}
```

Which helps decide each `Player's` rank at a given `GameTable` based on the number of `victoryPoints` she earned compared to the other `Players`.

Naturally, I've also got an integration test of this function:

```
package gcbgb


import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.transaction.*
import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
@TestFor(RoundService)
class RoundServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test tableRank"() {
        def player6 = new Player(name:"Player6").save(failOnError:true)
        def player5 = new Player(name:"Player5").save(failOnError:true)
        def player4 = new Player(name:"Player4").save(failOnError:true)
        def player3 = new Player(name:"Player3").save(failOnError:true)
        def player2 = new Player(name:"Player2").save(failOnError:true)
        def player1 = new Player(name:"Player1").save(failOnError:true)

        Round round1 = new Round(number:1, duration:"1.5").save(failOnError:true)
        GameTable gameTable1 = new GameTable(gameName:"Game1")
        round1.addToGameTables(gameTable1)
        round1.save(failOnError:true)

        Score score1 = Score.link(gameTable1, player1).setVictoryPoints(4).save(failOnError:true)
        Score score2 = Score.link(gameTable1, player2).setVictoryPoints(3).save(failOnError:true)
        Score score3 = Score.link(gameTable1, player3).setVictoryPoints(3).save(failOnError:true)
        Score score4 = Score.link(gameTable1, player4).setVictoryPoints(2).save(failOnError:true)
        Score score5 = Score.link(gameTable1, player5).setVictoryPoints(1).save(failOnError:true)

        expect:
            1 == service.tableRank(score1)
            3 == service.tableRank(score2)
            3 == service.tableRank(score3)
            4 == service.tableRank(score4)
            5 == service.tableRank(score5)
    }
}
```

However, when I run this test I get the following failure:

```
<testcase name="test tableRank" classname="gcbgb.RoundServiceSpec" time="8.329"><failure message="org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: victoryPoints of: gcbgb.Score" type="org.hibernate.QueryException">org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: victoryPoints of: gcbgb.Score
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1831)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1806)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.Junction.toSqlString(Junction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1773)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1687)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.list(AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1558)
    at gcbgb.RoundService.$tt__tableRank(RoundService.groovy:13)
    at gcbgb.RoundService.tableRank_closure2(RoundService.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at gcbgb.RoundServiceSpec.$tt__$spock_feature_0_0(RoundServiceSpec.groovy:40)
    at gcbgb.RoundServiceSpec.test tableRank_closure3(RoundServiceSpec.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:70)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.executeAndRollback(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:67)
    at gcbgb.RoundServiceSpec.test tableRank(RoundServiceSpec.groovy)
</failure></testcase>
```

Which suggests that there is a problem with my `Score.victoryPoints` member.

Comment: Are you sure, that hibernate expects exactly `victoryPoints` but not `victory_points`?

Comment: I'm not sure at all. Any suggestions as to how I could test that?

Comment: what statement do you have on this line (RoundService.groovy:13)

Comment: Also, have you looked into replacing the HQL with dynamic finders? If the dynamic finders work, then you can be sure HQL wasn't working.
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html

Comment: RoundService:13 is the body of the tableRank function. The line numbers don't match because I've taken out some irrelevant bits.

Comment: I've replaced the string query with the following dynamic finder `return Score.findAllByGameTableAndVictoryPointsGreaterThanEquals(score.gameTable, score.victoryPoints).size()` with mostly the same result.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the list of fields that grails thinks my class has?